# Alias a POSTGRES select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create new tables in the query and use them at the end for a final query. I don't remember what the syntax is and can't find it anywhere. (here is a basic example for illustration only).

```
phones as 
    (
        SELECT phone_number from customers
    )


emails as 
    (
        SELECT emails from customers
    )

// do something with both
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for `CTE's`

```
With phones as 
    (
        SELECT phone_number from customers
    )
,emails as 
    (
        SELECT emails from customers
    )
select * from phones--/emails
```

Comment: cool thanks. Will accept in 10 mins. Do i need to join now to use data from all tables? or can i say  select phones.phone, emails.email

Comment: @WilliamFalcon - It depends on the requirement. You current sample query makes not sense. Add sample data and expected result in next question.

Comment: yeah, it's a very simplified example for illustration. The as queries are fairly complex involving a bunch of joins. It's to do some calculations (group by users per month, see rate of growth, etc...)

Comment: @WilliamFalcon - You can `Join`,`union`, etc.. between phones and emails in your current example

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a Common Table Expression (CTE).  These are introduced using `with`:

```
with phones as (
      SELECT phone_number from customers
     ),
     emails as (
      SELECT emails from customers
    )
select . . .;
```

Your example selects don't seem particularly useful, but I assume they are just for illustration.